# Assigning a pointer variable to a const int in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, constants

I'm wondering if anyone can explain the following to me:  If I write

```
int i = 0;
float* pf = i;
```

I get a compile error (gcc 4.2.1):

```
error: invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘float*’
```

Makes sense - they are obviously two completely different types.  But if instead I write

```
const int i = 0;
float* pf = i;
```

It compiles without error.  Why should the 'const' make a difference on the right hand side of the assignment?  Isn't part of the idea of the 'const' keyword to be able to enforce type constraints for constant values?

Any explanation I have been able to come up with feels kind of bogus.  And none of my explanations also explain the fact that

```
const int i = 1;
float* pf = i;
```

fails to compile.  Can anyone offer an explanation?

Answer (score 10):

Your second example simply happens to be covered by the conversion rules as specified in *§4.10/1* (C++03):

> A null pointer constant is an integral constant expression (5.19) rvalue of integer type that evaluates to zero. A null pointer constant can be converted to a pointer type; the result is the null pointer value of that type and is distinguishable from every other value of pointer to object or pointer to function type.